# Making Android Icon with just an image and no background?

Tags: android, image, icons

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcNXg.png {Image of the Icon}

As you can see in the picture, there's a grey outline in the phone icon. How do I get rid of that background (in grey) and just have the image as an I con.

```
 <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/phone" />
```

This is what I have already.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/phone"
  android:background="@null" />
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageButtons always have that border around them, simply replace the ImageButton with ImageView to fix this. All classes and methods that work on TmageButton will work on ImageView like OnClickListeners etc.

```
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/phone" />
```